# How do I get private key from Bitcoin Wallet for Android

Tags: private-key

I had BTC in the Bitcoin Wallet during the hard fork and would like to get my bitcoin cash. I moved all the BTC out of the wallet before bitcoin gold happened.

Answer (score 1):

Export it with an export option or derive it from your word seed using a website or other tool.

I'd need more specific information to say more than that.